# Rest kit fails in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, ios8.1

For an enhancement am doing with rest kit. Its working Pretty cool on iOS7 but its terminating the program in iOS8 with no console termination log.Its showing that thread broken in JSONKit.m. I am trying from yesterday to find the problem, but I failed to find the problem even.No termination log in console makes me mad. [image: screen shot]

Comment: You can look this GitHub issues, maybe help you:
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/pull/158
and in the specific:
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/pull/141

Comment: What version of RestKit? Do you need to be using JSONKit?

Comment: thanks alot @weso problem is solved,i was struggled for 48 hours. you can post a detailed answer here.. it'll be helpfull for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a RestKit issue, you can find the fix here: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/pull/158